# go lang plugin for Intellij IDEA 14.0.x

Tags: intellij-idea, go

Is it possible to setup go language pluing for Intellij IDEA 14.0.3 version?

I tried to download the binary plugin (jar) from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047?pr=idea but the version 0.9.15.3 listed here is old and does not recognize GOROOT and GOPATH.
I tried to build the latest plugin using sources from https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin using Intellij but failed to setup the SDK.

Is there a latest binary version of the go lang plugin available?

Comment: Why not update Intellij?

Comment: perhaps it would be better to install LiteIDE

Comment: @inf money constraints :)

Comment: Can you not use the community edition for Go development? (Besides that, is the update from 14.0 to 14.1 not free?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to IDEA 14.1+ or use the IntelliJ Community.

Original answer:
You can use the free version of IntelliJ Community with the latest version of the plugin and everything should work fine. Also, Android Studio for example is compatible with the plugin as well.
Unfortunately the plugin has some internal dependencies which makes it hard to port back and maintain for multiple IDEA versions. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the exact answer your are looking for but their is a separate IDE for go developer . it has some unique features you must try

#### GOLAND

First month is free.

Comment: SO is considered for opensource products. Your answer might be considered as spamm. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349792/2096986

Answer (score -1):

I also faced up this problem couple days ago. You can download nightly version of go plugin from this link.

[You must install this plugin via browse your download folder not repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047?pr=&showAllUpdates=true)

Comment: But this is not how it should be done. While it's true that you can download it manually from the website, you should read the readme and get the alpha/nightly repository added to the IDE. Also, we don't support the 14.0.x branch anymore as it's too complicated (and soon IDEA 15 will be around).